# How to get exit status of a particular command in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, pipe, exit-status

I am running this `while` loop in a script to take `mysqldump` and compress it, but I want to `exit` the script if the `table` doesn't exist. Below is what I have tried.

```
while read TABLES; do
    sudo mysqldump $DB $TABLES | gzip -f > $DB.$TABLES.sql.gz
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo "mysqldump Query executed with error !!"
        exit 1
    fi
done < file
```

But this will give the exit status of `gzip -f`, but not of `mysqldump`. I know I can get the exit status of `mysqldump` if I am not using `gzip` there, but is there any way in this method to get the exit ststus for `mysqldump`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can make use of PIPESTATUS variable to get the exit status of each element of the pipeline.

```
if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ];then
        echo "mysqldump Query executed with error !!"
        exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not getting the expected result. `++ sudo mysqldump mysql use
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "use"
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ read TABLES`. I used like `while read TABLES; do `sudo mysqldump $DB $TABLES | gzip -f > $DB.$TABLES.sql.gz`; if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ];then echo "mysqldump Query executed with error !!";exit 1;fi;done < file`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I got it right now. I had `backticks` in the script which was causing the issue. Removing it will work. Thanks @rakesh

Comment: @prado Glad it worked. If helped, mark question as answered.

Comment: Bash only? Not POSIX shell?

Comment: @ Franklin Yu  executiing this script in posix mode, it's giving a proper output. P.S : not much hands on experience/knowledge in posix.

Comment: If you ran out of disk `gzip` will give an error so you also need to check for `${PIPESTATUS[1]} -ne 0`. The result is an array `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` = `0 0`.